R - Total sum of all named items in list elements
I am attempting to sum the number of atoms for each element in the chemical_formula vector:
chemical_formula <- c("CaF2", "Ca3(PO4)2", "FePO4", "KCl", "K3PO4", "K2SO4", "Mg3(PO4)2", "NaCl",
"Na3PO4", "Na2SO4", "SiO2", "CaSO4", "KAsO2", "KBr", "KI", "LiCl", "MnSO4", "CaS", "CuAsHO3",
"AlK(SO4)2", "(H2O)12", "ZnCl2", "CaCO3", "NaHCO3", "AsI3", "AuCl4Na", "Se", "K2Cr2O7")

cell_salts_atoms <- CHNOSZ::makeup(chemical_formula)

# > CHNOSZ::makeup(chemical_formula)
# [[1]]
# Ca  F 
#  1  2 
# 
# [[2]]
# Ca  O  P 
#  3  8  2 
# 
# [[3]]
# Fe  P  O 
#  1  1  4 
# 
# [[4]]
#  K Cl 
#  1  1 
# 
# [[5]]
# K P O 
# 3 1 4 
# 
# [[6]]
# K S O 
# 2 1 4 
# 
# [[7]]
# Mg  O  P 
#  3  8  2 
# 
# [[8]]
# Na Cl 
#  1  1 
# 
# [[9]]
# Na  P  O 
#  3  1  4 
# 
# [[10]]
# Na  S  O 
#  2  1  4 
# 
# [[11]]
# Si  O 
#  1  2 
# 
# [[12]]
# Ca  S  O 
#  1  1  4 
# 
# [[13]]
#  K As  O 
#  1  1  2 
# 
# [[14]]
#  K Br 
#  1  1 
# 
# [[15]]
# K I 
# 1 1 
# 
# [[16]]
# Li Cl 
#  1  1 
# 
# [[17]]
# Mn  S  O 
#  1  1  4
# 
# [[18]]
# Ca  S
#  1  1
# 
# [[19]]
# Cu As  H  O
#  1  1  1  3
# 
# [[20]]
# Al  K  O  S
#  1  1  8  2
# 
# [[21]]
#  H  O
# 24 12
# 
# [[22]]
# Zn Cl
#  1  2
# 
# [[23]]
# Ca  C  O
#  1  1  3
# 
# [[24]]
# Na  H  C  O
#  1  1  1  3
# 
# [[25]]
# As  I
#  1  3
# 
# [[26]]
# Au Cl Na
#  1  4  1
# 
# [[27]]
# Se
#  1
# 
# [[28]]
#  K Cr  O
#  2  2  7

cell_salts_atoms_matrix <- lapply(cell_salts_atoms, as.matrix)

# > cell_salts_atoms_matrix
# [[1]]
#    [,1]
# Ca    1
# F     2
# 
# [[2]]
#    [,1]
# Ca    3
# O     8
# P     2
# 
# [[3]]
#    [,1]
# Fe    1
# P     1
# O     4
# 
# [[4]]
#    [,1]
# K     1
# Cl    1
# 
# [[5]]
#   [,1]
# K    3
# P    1
# O    4
# 
# [[6]]
#   [,1]
# K    2
# S    1
# O    4
# 
# [[7]]
#    [,1]
# Mg    3
# O     8
# P     2
# 
# [[8]]
#    [,1]
# Na    1
# Cl    1
# 
# [[9]]
#    [,1]
# Na    3
# P     1
# O     4
# 
# [[10]]
#    [,1]
# Na    2
# S     1
# O     4
# 
# [[11]]
#    [,1]
# Si    1
# O     2
# 
# [[12]]
#    [,1]
# Ca    1
# S     1
# O     4
# 
# [[13]]
#    [,1]
# K     1
# As    1
# O     2
# 
# [[14]]
#    [,1]
# K     1
# Br    1
# 
# [[15]]
#   [,1]
# K    1
# I    1
# 
# [[16]]
#    [,1]
# Li    1
# Cl    1
# 
# [[17]]
#    [,1]
# Mn    1
# S     1
# O     4
# 
# [[18]]
#    [,1]
# Ca    1
# S     1
# 
# [[19]]
#    [,1]
# Cu    1
# As    1
# H     1
# O     3
# 
# [[20]]
#    [,1]
# Al    1
# K     1
# O     8
# S     2
# 
# [[21]]
#   [,1]
# H   24
# O   12
# 
# [[22]]
#    [,1]
# Zn    1
# Cl    2
# 
# [[23]]
#    [,1]
# Ca    1
# C     1
# O     3
# 
# [[24]]
#    [,1]
# Na    1
# H     1
# C     1
# O     3
# 
# [[25]]
#    [,1]
# As    1
# I     3
# 
# [[26]]
#    [,1]
# Au    1
# Cl    4
# Na    1
# 
# [[27]]
#    [,1]
# Se    1
# 
# [[28]]
#    [,1]
# K     2
# Cr    2
# O     7


I want the result to resemble the following:
Se 1
Au 1
As 2
Ca 6

I have tried cell_salts_atoms_sum <- lapply(cell_salts_atoms, sum); however, that only provides the total sum for each list element rather than sum of each named component.
What's the best method to produce the desired result?
UPDATE
The structure of the result does not matter, I just wanted a sum of the atoms.
Thus,
Se   Au   As   Ca
1    1    2    6

is also acceptable.

Please try
library(CHNOSZ)

cell_salts_atoms <- CHNOSZ::makeup(chemical_formula, sum=F)

data <- map(cell_salts_atoms, \(x) {
  data.frame(val=x %>% as_vector()) %>% rownames_to_column(var='element')
})

data1 <- do.call(rbind, data) %>% arrange(element) %>% group_by(element) %>% summarise(sum=sum(val))


# A tibble: 24 × 2
   element  sum
   <chr> <dbl>
 1 Al        1
 2 As        3
 3 Au        1
 4 Br        1
 5 C         2
 6 Ca        7
 7 Cl        9
 8 Cr        2
 9 Cu        1
10 F         2
# ℹ 14 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows


thank you for your answer. I hadn't looked at the makeup function arguments until I read your answer (which was after I devised the answer below); however, after I saw the sum argument I wrote the following: cell_salts_atoms <- CHNOSZ::makeup(chemical_formula, sum = TRUE). Using the sum = TRUE argument simplifies both your and my answers.

Use the sum= argument.  Omit stack if a named vector output is ok.
makeup(chemical_formula, sum = TRUE) |> stack()

giving
   values ind
1       1  Al
2       3  As
3       1  Au
4       1  Br
5       2   C
6       7  Ca
7       9  Cl
8       2  Cr
9       1  Cu
10      2   F
11      1  Fe
12     26   H
13      4   I
14     12   K
15      1  Li
16      3  Mg
17      1  Mn
18      8  Na
19     84   O
20      7   P
21      7   S
22      1  Se
23      1  Si
24      1  Zn


You can use dplyr::bind_rows() and take the column sums:
colSums(dplyr::bind_rows(cell_salts_atoms), na.rm = TRUE)
# Ca  F  O  P Fe  K Cl  S Mg Na Si As Br  I Li Mn Cu  H Al Zn  C Au Se Cr 
#  7  2 84  7  1 12  9  7  3  8  1  3  1  4  1  1  1 26  1  1  2  1  1  2 


I devised the following solution to the question that I posed:
chemical_formula <- c("CaF2", "Ca3(PO4)2", "FePO4", "KCl", "K3PO4", "K2SO4", "Mg3(PO4)2",
"NaCl", "Na3PO4", "Na2SO4", "SiO2", "CaSO4", "KAsO2", "KBr", "KI", "LiCl", "MnSO4", "CaS",
"CuAsHO3", "AlK(SO4)2", "(H2O)12", "ZnCl2", "CaCO3", "NaHCO3", "AsI3", "AuCl4Na", "Se",
"K2Cr2O7")

cell_salts_atoms <- CHNOSZ::makeup(chemical_formula)

cell_salts_atoms_DF1 <- lapply(cell_salts_atoms, as.data.frame, keep.rownames = TRUE)

cell_salts_atoms_DF2 <- lapply(cell_salts_atoms_DF1, t)

cell_salts_atoms_matrix1 <- lapply(cell_salts_atoms_DF2, as.matrix)

cell_salts_atoms_matrix2 <- matsbyname::setrownames_byname(cell_salts_atoms_matrix1,
"value")

cell_salts_atoms_matrix3 <- matsbyname::cumsum_byname(cell_salts_atoms_matrix2)

cell_salts_atoms_final <- cell_salts_atoms_matrix3[[28]]

The following is the result:
# > cell_salts_atoms_final
#       Al As Au Br C Ca Cl Cr Cu F Fe  H I  K Li Mg Mn Na  O P S Se Si Zn
# value  1  3  1  1 2  7  9  2  1 2  1 26 4 12  1  3  1  8 84 7 7  1  1  1

